# How can you specify your terminal emulator in Corda

Tags: corda

Xterm is used when running Corda locally on one computer using gradle.

Is there a way to specify your terminal editor when running as suggested by the following issue?

https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/2605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely share your pain on this. The way that runnodes has its tooling baked in makes it impossible for you to customize how the cordform plugin runs the nodes without digging into the internals.

Some other ideas for you

- one thing you could do would be to stop using cordform altogether and run your corda network using dockerform (example here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Features/dockerform-yocordapp/build.gradle#L93) so that the plugin doesn't need to actually create new terminals.
- the much harder way would be to actually download the corda gradle plugins (https://github.com/corda/corda-gradle-plugins#installing-locally) and install it locally with your edits to the cordform task so that it opens the terminal of your choice. You may be able to PR them as the cordform task that's usually used to generate the runnodes script comes from here as far as I know.

As a separate note, I saw your github issue and I was disappointed by how that got handled. I'm sorry you had that experience and I'm going to dig into that issue internally to find out what's happening with that.

feel free to reach out to me (David Awad) on slack.corda.net and I can let you know what's going on there.

Thanks as always

Comment: Thanks for answer, and the explanation why it's an issue